# Having a <tr> behave as a single row when using <td rowspan ="2">

Tags: html, css, excel, frontend, css-tables

So, I have a spreadsheet that I need to display as an HTML table, it's a rather easy task but I found out that the styling proved rather challenging. There are several hundred entries in the spreadsheet and so I want to use zebra striping for better readability. The pattern should be like the one in the image below, every 1st cell of every other row needs to span on two rows while the other cells span on three columns. When I try to style the`<tr>` using `nth-child()` I get the pattern shown when you run the snippet. It seems like the rows having `rowspan="2"` do not behave as a single row. Ideally, I want all items that have the same number also to have the same colour. Any workarounds for this issue?

[image: Desired pattern]

*Desired pattern*

My HTML and CSS code:

```css
tr:nth-child(odd) {
        background-color: #BDD7EE;
      }
tr:nth-child(even) {
        background-color: #C6E0B4;
      }
```

```html
`<table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="2">Case1</td>
          <td colspan="3">Issue1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3">Decision1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="2">Case2</td>
          <td colspan="3">Issue2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3">Decision2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="2">Case3</td>
          <td colspan="3">Issue3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3">Decision3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="2">Case4</td>
          <td colspan="3">Issue4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3">Decision4</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>`
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest the following:

```css
:root {
  --odd: #BDD7EE;
  --even: #C6E0B4;
}

tr {
  background-color: var(--odd);
}

tr:nth-child(4n + 1),
tr:nth-child(4n + 2) {
  background-color: var(--odd);
}

tr:nth-child(4n + 3),
tr:nth-child(4n + 4) {
  background-color: var(--even);
}

td {
  background-color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">Case1</td>
      <td colspan="3">Issue1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">Decision1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">Case2</td>
      <td colspan="3">Issue2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">Decision2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">Case3</td>
      <td colspan="3">Issue3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">Decision3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">Case4</td>
      <td colspan="3">Issue4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">Decision4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>`
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ba8krLn6/)

Or, given that multiple `<tbody>` elements are permitted in a `<table>`, there's the possibility of:

```css
:root {
  --odd: #BDD7EE;
  --even: #C6E0B4;
}

tbody:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: var(--odd);
}

tbody:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: var(--even);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">Case1</td>
      <td colspan="3">Issue1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">Decision1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">Case2</td>
      <td colspan="3">Issue2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">Decision2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">Case3</td>
      <td colspan="3">Issue3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">Decision3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">Case4</td>
      <td colspan="3">Issue4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">Decision4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>`
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ba8krLn6/1/).

Another option, if you're able to move away from a `<table>` layout, is to use a list along with CSS Grid, for example:

```css
/* defining the CSS properties here: */
:root {
  --odd: #BDD7EE;
  --even: #C6E0B4;
}

/* a simple CSS reset: */
*,
 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ol {
  /* to allow for better styling, we're using a CSS
     counter in place of the default counter, and
     here we set the <ol> element(s) to reset the
     counter ('listCount') that we're using: */
  counter-reset: listCount;
  /* removing the default list-style: */
  list-style: none;
  width: 80vw;
}

li {
  /* using Grid layout: */
  display: grid;
  /* defining the named grid areas: */
  grid-template-areas:
    "index issue"
    "index description";
  /* defining the gap between rows (0.5em) and columns
     (0.3em) */
  gap: 0.5em 0.3em;
  /* defining the column widths: */
  grid-template-columns: 2rem 1fr;
  /* defining the margins around the <li> element in
     the block axis (top and bottom in a left-to-right,
     top-to-bottom language): */
  margin-block: 0.5em;
}

li::before {
  /* setting the counter as the content (followed by
     a period) in decimal format: */
  content: counter(listCount, decimal) '. ';
  /* incrementing the listCount counter */
  counter-increment: listCount;
  /* assigning the ::before pseudo-element to appear in
     the 'index' named grid area: */
  grid-area: index;
}

/* setting the --odd background for those elements matched
   by the selectors: */
li:nth-child(odd)::before,
li:nth-child(odd)>* {
  background-color: var(--odd);
}

li:nth-child(even)::before,
li:nth-child(even)>* {
  background-color: var(--even);
}
```

```html
<ol class="reports">
  <li>
    <h2 class="issue">Issue 1</h2>
    <div class="description">Description 1</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2 class="issue">Issue 2</h2>
    <div class="description">Description 2</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2 class="issue">Issue 3</h2>
    <div class="description">Description 3</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2 class="issue">Issue 4</h2>
    <div class="description">Description 4</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2 class="issue">Issue 5</h2>
    <div class="description">Description 5</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2 class="issue">Issue 6</h2>
    <div class="description">Description 6</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2 class="issue">Issue 7</h2>
    <div class="description">Description 7</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2 class="issue">Issue 8</h2>
    <div class="description">Description 8</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2 class="issue">Issue 9</h2>
    <div class="description">Description 9</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2 class="issue">Issue 10</h2>
    <div class="description">Description 10</div>
  </li>
</ol>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ba8krLn6/2/).

References:

- [`:nth-child()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child).

Comment: Thanks for your answer solution #2 with the multiple <tbody> elements looks pretty neat.  Is using multiple <tbody> elements for a single table semantically correct though?

Comment: You're very welcome indeed, I'm glad to have helped! As for 'semantics,' I don't know of any adverse implications of grouping each double 'row' in its own `<tbody>`, and the specification explicitly allows such grouping with multiple `<tbody>` elements; so I don't *believe* there are any issues, but I've not undertaken any research either way.